# Merging two string rows into one using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv having rows like this:

| Year 1 | Year 1 | Year 1 | Year 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 | Month 4 |

I want these first two columns to be merged into one like this:

| Year1-Month1 | Year1-Month2 | etc.

I am reading the csv using pandas dataframe.
All the answers on stack overflow combine the two columns but not rows. Please help.

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: (tl;dr wrap them with triple-back ticks or indent by 4 spaces)

Comment: Do you want the first two **rows** to be merged instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert first 2 rows of data to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0, 1])
```

And then join values by `-`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('-'.join)
```

Or use `f-string`s:

```
df.columns = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
```

Comment: Should I replace a, b with the rows index? Can you please elaborate

Comment: @sheharbano Surely you already have a pandas dataframe? You didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: @sheharbano - Added `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0, 1])` for `MultiIndex` in columns.

Comment: Can we specify any other row index in a case where the rows to be merged are not on top?

Comment: @sheharbano - Do you think e.g. first row and fourth row of data?

Comment: This statement is not working if I specify index 8, 9

Comment: @sheharbano - there is error? Is possible see data which failed?

Comment: @sheharbano - Tested and need tranpose like `df.columns = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in df.iloc[[0, 3]].T.to_numpy()] `